# mongoose: how to calcluate seconds from the hours, minutes and seconds field in a Date collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am storing times in a date field and need a way to convert the times to number of seconds in a day.  I tried the following but am receiving errors indicating that $multiply only supports numeric types and not objects.

This is a sample of how I am calculating the seconds, mind you I am trying to use this as where criteria to filter any records that I am not interesting in:

```
{ "$multiply": [ { "$hour": "$rule.startTime" }, 3600 ] }
```

I thought the hour operator would return a number that would then be used in the multiply above.  What is a way that I could pull this off?  In a nutshell, I need a way to get the hour field to perform this operation.  How could I get the hour field to use in multiply operation?

Comment: Could you use the date operators in https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-date/ ?

Comment: That is what I tried above using the $hour operator.  The error acted as if the multiply function was getting an object, according to the error.  Seems like it did not return the numerical value.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't reading very carefully! If you split it into two different projection stages it seems to work. I guess it just gets confused about how to parse it when it's in a single stage

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you did it?

Comment: `db.test_coll.aggregate([{$project: {hour: {$hour: "$d"}} }, {$project: {updated: { $multiply: ["$hour", 3]}}}])` (docs looked like `{d: Date}`)

Comment: Thanks.  I will try it.  Can I use projection fields in a $redact operator?

Comment: No clue, I haven't used $redact before

Comment: @willis Thanks.  That worked.  Found a way to do it with redact plus the code you supplied above.